# Can't click to custom item in android-uitableview

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using [android-uitableview](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview)

And I have this problem:

When I use this code:

```
 LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
ViewItem viewItem = new ViewItem(view);
getUITableView().addViewItem(viewItem);
```

When I click this button, I can't go to `onClick(int index)` <= the problem

But when I use `getUITableView().addBasicItem` , I can handle the click.

How can I handle when I click the custom view ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they have not implement `onClick` for `addViewItem` but they do for `addBasicItem`.

[Source Code](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview/blob/master/android-uitableview/src/br/com/dina/ui/widget/UITableView.java)

You can call `getUITableView().setClickListener(...)`

Comment: Oh, i have to implement onClick for addBasicItem for myself. It works like a champ